# Running a websocket server from within a ros2 node

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rclpy

I have an application that requires me to run a websocket server from within a ROS2 node, but I'm running into issues with using async websocket code with rclpy. The typical way of running one of these seems to be to use asyncio's run_forever() function, which prevents ROS from interacting with the node at all.

```
start_server = websockets.serve(self.echo, ip, 8080)
self.schedule_async_function(start_server)
thread = threading.Thread(asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever(), daemon=True)
thread.start()
```

I've previously used 0-second async sleep calls to work around this issue with ROS, but although this lets ROS run, it also breaks the websocket server. I tried things like this:

```
async def spin(executor: rclpy.executors.SingleThreadedExecutor):
    while rclpy.ok():
        executor.spin_once()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

using it to spin an executor like this:

```
node = Node()
ip = ni.ifaddresses('wlan0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
node.get_logger().info(ip)
start_server = websockets.serve(node.echo, ip, 8080)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
# Use the SingleThreadedExecutor to spin the node.
executor = rclpy.executors.SingleThreadedExecutor()
executor.add_node(node)
loop.run_until_complete(spin(executor))
```

but again, ROS works but the websocket server stops receiving any callbacks.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this?
I could migrate this node to c++, if rclcpp would be more suitable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved it immediately.

The only change necessary was to add a timeout_sec=0 to the spin_once() call, like this:

```
async def spin(executor: rclpy.executors.SingleThreadedExecutor):
    while rclpy.ok():
        executor.spin_once(timeout_sec=0)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

And now it works! This does break some of the intent of async, because it becomes a busy loop. You can change the timeout of spin_once to something a bit higher to reduce looping, at the cost of latency on async calls.